# trying to define a delete function where user enters a name and clicks on the button and the row is deleted

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, error-handling, typeerror

trying to define a delete function where in the user enters a name and clicks on the delete button and the row containing the data delete with the help of tkinter and sqlite in python.

## this is my delete function:

```
def deleteMovie(name):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('moviedata.db')
    sql = "Delete from movies WHERE name=?"
    conn.execute(sql,(name,))
    messagebox.showinfo("information","MOVIE DELETED")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
#this is my entry
```

code:

```
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("SP Movie Admin Form")
window.geometry("400x250")
window.resizable(0, 0)

lName = ttk.Label(window,text="Name",padding=2)
lName.grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan=1)
nameent = StringVar()
nameent = ttk.Entry(window,textvariable=nameent)
nameent.grid(row=1,column=2,columnspan=3)
```

## this is my button:

```
buttondelete = ttk.Button(window,text="Delete",command=deleteMovie)
buttondelete.grid(row=7,column=2)

window.mainloop()
```

this is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gayat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: deleteMovie() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button callback needs to fetch the data it needs, rather than having it passed in. If you want to keep your function that accepts a parameter, you can create a function specifically for the button which fetches the value and then calls `deleteMovie`.

For example:

```
def deleteCommand():
    name = nameent.get()
    deleteMovie(name)
```

Then, have your button call the callback:

```
buttondelete = ttk.Button(window,text="Delete",command=deleteCommand)
```

You can of course use a single function that does both of these by removing the parameter and calling the `get()` method:

```
def deleteMovie():
    name = nameent.get()
    conn = sqlite3.connect('moviedata.db')
    sql = "Delete from movies WHERE name=?"
    conn.execute(sql,(name,))
    messagebox.showinfo("information","MOVIE DELETED")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError: deleteMovie() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

Of course, what is the name of the movie you want to delete?

I guess it should be `nameent`, but you also named your entry `nameent`. won't work.

You have to set the `StringVar()` variable different from the `Entry` variable and then use `.get()` to get the value in the `StringVar()`.

```
def deleteMovie():
    name=movie_name.get()
    conn = sqlite3.connect('moviedata.db')
    sql = "Delete from movies WHERE name=?"
    conn.execute(sql,(name,))
    messagebox.showinfo("information","MOVIE DELETED")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
#this is my entry
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("SP Movie Admin Form")
window.geometry("400x250")
window.resizable(0, 0)

lName = ttk.Label(window,text="Name",padding=2)
lName.grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan=1)
movie_name= StringVar()
nameent = ttk.Entry(window,textvariable=movie_name)
nameent.grid(row=1,column=2,columnspan=3)

buttondelete = ttk.Button(window,text="Delete",command=deleteMovie)
buttondelete.grid(row=7,column=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome, howbeit, comments should be for clarification or additional suggestions. If it worked just mark it as answer.